# influxdb and grafana timezone mismatch

Tags: time, influxdb, grafana

I'm trying to use curl to write datapoints into to influxdb and then display with grafana.

The following successfully writes to influxdb, but the time is in UTC

# curl -i -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=db_fio" --data-binary "test result=22"
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Request-Id: a333902d-7c69-11e5-802d-000000000000
X-Influxdb-Version: 0.9.4.1
Date: Tue, 27 Oct 2015 05:14:45 GMT

# date
Mon Oct 26 22:17:40 PDT 2015

When I try to display the datapoints in grafana I can not as they are in the future for my timezone (PDT), even thought both services are running on the same server.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get grafana and influxdb to be on the same time?

Answer (score 10):

You can set UTC timezone per dashboard.

http://play.grafana.org/dashboard/db/new-features-in-v20?editview=settings [image: Grafana timezone]

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 4):

InfluxDB only supports UTC. There is no way to write or query points in any other timezone. The [feature request for timezone support](https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/2074) describes some of the challenges that make this a difficult feature to implement.

I am not familiar enough with Grafana to know if it can do timezone translation on the results from InfluxDB.